# Best solution for high performance search of read-only data

Tags: c#, performance, search, singleton, in-memory-database

I'm building a search engine based on data that doesn't change too often. The main idea is to have the data be driven from a database and be explicitly cached into an in-memory store on startup or on-demand. The number of records is about ~10k.

I'm using .NET and was thinking implementing a cross thread search repository as a singleton exposing the data as read-only arrays which can be easily queried with LINQ.

What will the memory footprint be implementing this kind of approach? I don't want to use unnecessary resources and processing. Are there any "best practices" to consider?

Comment: If this is done in a web context, you can use the cache provided by the framework. No need to write your own.

Comment: Also, if you're using [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) as a persistence strategy, then [this is already handled for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3)

Comment: Isn't using Entity Framework a bit overkill for read only in memory data? I literally want to only repopulate everything on demand from a periodic trigger. The store is implemented outside of the web context.

Comment: What kind of queries are you running against your data? Is it full-text search?

Comment: @FanieReynders  ~10k is nothing. Even you use the worst code, all modern computers can handle it well.

Comment: @pwee167 no full-text searching. Basic 'where' query to evaluate results within a given criteria and filters.

Comment: @EZI what  record count would start to impact the performance?

Comment: @FanieReynders start experimenting it and if you have a problem, ask a concrete question. Otherwise, what you only get will be general suggestions like *use this*, whithout knowing your specific cases.